# Algorithm to determine number of total orderings of a poset

Tags: order-theory

In a poset with relation $\geq$, is there an algorithm to find the number of total orderings of this poset? If there is, is it P or NP? Is it equivalent to finding the number of total orderings of only the set of incomparable pairs?

Comment: By "number of total orderings" you mean number of totally ordered subsets, or number of total orderings that extend given partial ordering?

Comment: @mihaild I mean total orderings that extend the poset, sorry if this is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

What you’re looking for is the complexity of counting the **linear extensions** of a poset. [Brightwell and Winkler](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00383444) showed that the problem is  #P-complete.

Creating a linear extension amounts to resolving all of the incomparabilites—but that requires avoiding violating transitivity. You have to honor all the original comparabilities and ensure that your new comparabilities don’t contradict one another.